# Recursively traverse XML and print output into excel/csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

My XML Looks like the below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DEFTABLE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Folder.xsd">
    <FOLDERA DC="123" VR="A1" PT="UN">
        <TASK TASKID="1" APLN="StuffA" DATE="20211117" Name="StuffA1" >
            <COMMONA NAME="1233" TYPE="E" />
            <COMMONB NAME="ABCD" />
        </TASK>
        <TASK TASKID="2" APLN="StuffA" DATE="20211117" Name="StuffA2" >
        </TASK>
    </FOLDERA>
    <FOLDERB DC="123" VR="A1" PT="UN" ATTIA="UN" ATTIB="UN">
        <TASK TASKID="3" APLN="StuffB" DATE="20211117" Name="StuffA1" >
            <COMMONA NAME="1233" TYPE="E" />
            <COMMONB NAME="ABCD" />
        </TASK>
        <TASK TASKID="4" APLN="StuffC" DATE="20211117" Name="StuffA2" >
        </TASK>
    </FOLDERB>
</DEFTABLE>
```

I am doing reading it using `ElementTree`:

```
tree = ET.parse("./Test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    print(child.tag,child.attrib)
    for x in root.iter('JOB'):
        print(x.tag,x.attrib)
```

The issue is it is printing all the root value severyti,me:

```
FOLDERA {'DC': '123', 'VR': 'A1', 'PT': 'UN'}
TASK {'TASKID': '1', 'APLN': 'StuffA', 'DATE': '20211117', 'Name': 'StuffA1'}
TASK {'TASKID': '2', 'APLN': 'StuffA', 'DATE': '20211117', 'Name': 'StuffA2'}
TASK {'TASKID': '3', 'APLN': 'StuffB', 'DATE': '20211117', 'Name': 'StuffA1'}
TASK {'TASKID': '4', 'APLN': 'StuffC', 'DATE': '20211117', 'Name': 'StuffA2'}
FOLDERB {'DC': '123', 'VR': 'A1', 'PT': 'UN', 'ATTIA': 'UN', 'ATTIB': 'UN'}
TASK {'TASKID': '1', 'APLN': 'StuffA', 'DATE': '20211117', 'Name': 'StuffA1'}
TASK {'TASKID': '2', 'APLN': 'StuffA', 'DATE': '20211117', 'Name': 'StuffA2'}
TASK {'TASKID': '3', 'APLN': 'StuffB', 'DATE': '20211117', 'Name': 'StuffA1'}
TASK {'TASKID': '4', 'APLN': 'StuffC', 'DATE': '20211117', 'Name': 'StuffA2'}
```

I was hoping to get output like this:

```
FOLDERA {'DC': '123', 'VR': 'A1', 'PT': 'UN'}, TASK {'TASKID': '1', 'APLN': 'StuffA', 'DATE': '20211117', 'Name': 'StuffA1'}
FOLDERA {'DC': '123', 'VR': 'A1', 'PT': 'UN'}, TASK {'TASKID': '2', 'APLN': 'StuffA', 'DATE': '20211117', 'Name': 'StuffA2'}
FOLDERB {'DC': '123', 'VR': 'A1', 'PT': 'UN', 'ATTIA': 'UN', 'ATTIB': 'UN'},TASK {'TASKID': '3', 'APLN': 'StuffB', 'DATE': '20211117', 'Name': 'StuffA1'}
FOLDERB {'DC': '123', 'VR': 'A1', 'PT': 'UN', 'ATTIA': 'UN', 'ATTIB': 'UN'}, TASK {'TASKID': '4', 'APLN': 'StuffC', 'DATE': '20211117', 'Name': 'StuffA2'}
```

i.e. Each attribute being a column in a table.

Any inputs on how to traverse it properly? Please note that the number of attibutes can vary for TASKs as well as FOLDERS

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a recursive approach if you are only interested in outputting the 2 levels of FOLDERs and TASKs. To obtain TASKS under each FOLDER you can simply call the `iter` method bound to each child node instead of the root node:

```
for child in root:
    for task in child.iter('TASK'):
        print(*(f'{node.tag} {node.attrib}' for node in (child, task)), sep=', ')
```